# Transitioning back to first view after a sequence of modal views?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am creating a simple game that has the following view sequence:

Menu -> Select Difficulty -> Game -> Game Over -> Menu

The first four transitions are done like this:

```
- (IBAction)newGame {
    // Transition to select difficulty view controller.
    [self presentModalViewController:[[SelectDifficultyViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}
```

What would the best way be to transition from the GameOver view back to the menu view, and dismiss and dealloc the GameOver, Game, and SelectDifficulty views while only showing one animated transition?

Comment: Whenever dismissing any view controller write its method in its parent view controller, so that the parent will handle all the necessary things and everything will happen accordingly, in a hierarchical way.

Comment: So `[[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way may involve refactoring your dialog code (note: I don't claim to present the best way here, and you shouldn't ask for a best way as that will cause a debate). Modal dialogs are not meant to stick around for long; allow the user to select a difficulty, and then hide the dialog for your game. A game over screen can also be a dialog over your main application window.

Of the below options, 1 provides immediate access to all of your application states, but 2 is closer to best practice as it separates the game logic from the menu nav/settings logic.

---

**Option 1: Combine your menu and game views into a single view controller**

Your main window's view hierarchy would be:

```
UIView (root view) --- UIView (menu layer) --- (all of your menu subviews)
                   \-- UIView (game layer) --- (all of your game subviews)
```

The new flow would be something like

Main view (menu layer) -> Select Difficulty (modal) -> Main view (game layer) -> Game Over (modal) -> Main view (menu layer)

The transition from game over to menu then becomes:

1. Both of these happen within a single animation block

   a) Game Over dialog alpha -> `0.0f`

   b) Menu layer alpha -> `1.0f`
2. Perform the underlying `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(false)` operation

---

**Option 2: Have separate view controllers for your menu and game views**

Your main window's view hierarchy would be:

```
UIViewController (root) --- UIView (menu view) --- (all your menu subviews)
UIViewController        --- UIView (game view) --- (all your game subviews)
```

You can toggle between active view controllers by setting your `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` property.

The new flow would be something like

Menu view -> Select Difficulty (modal) -> Game view -> Game Over (modal) -> Menu view

The transition from game over to menu then becomes:

1. Both of these happen within a single animation block

   a) Game Over dialog alpha -> `0.0f`

   b) Set `rootViewController` to menu view
2. Perform the underlying `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(false)` operation

Comment: Right, how should the "menu layer" and "game layer" interact with each other? Should they still each have their own view controllers? Sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm just getting started with iOS development.

Comment: The menu and game layer would both be a view within the *same* view controller. You show one and hide the other, but they're both in the same view controller.

Comment: Ohh, I see. That looks like a pretty good way to do it, thanks. Is it generally accepted as good practice to combine these sorts of things in to the same controller?

Comment: According to [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108664/whats-the-proper-way-to-organize-viewcontrollers-and-xib) answer, no, it's not best practice. I'll present an alternative using two view controllers here.

Comment: Ok, so with that approach, both view controllers need references to the UIWindow in order to change the root controller, correct?

Comment: No, they probably don't. You can reference your application's main window either from the application delegate (`[(AppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]`) or via the `keyWindow` static property (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`).

Comment: I've implemented your Option 2, but the animations don't look very good. The new view doesn't fade in, just the old one fading out which looks messy. Also, when the modal views display using the crossdisssolve animation, there seems to be a glimpse of the menuview or gameview in the background, even when they have been deallocated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15928/discussion-between-darvids0n-and-danielgibbs)